# Error parsing media type 'application.xml' Jersey REST client

Tags: rest, jersey

I'm getting this Exception when I run the client.

[image]

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing media type 'application.xml'
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:79)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:53)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.valueOf(MediaType.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.PartialRequestBuilder.type(PartialRequestBuilder.java:92)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.type(WebResource.java:347)
    at com.rest.client.EmpGETClient.main(EmpGETClient.java:15)
Caused by: java.text.ParseException: End of header
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReaderImpl.getNextCharacter(HttpHeaderReaderImpl.java:168)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReaderImpl.next(HttpHeaderReaderImpl.java:129)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReaderImpl.next(HttpHeaderReaderImpl.java:124)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.header.reader.HttpHeaderReader.nextSeparator(HttpHeaderReader.java:116)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.valueOf(MediaTypeProvider.java:90)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.header.MediaTypeProvider.fromString(MediaTypeProvider.java:77)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: The request builder method `type` expects a valid content type. `application.xml` looks like a file name, what you want is probably `application/xml`, using Jersey's `MediaType` class can save you some confusion as it declares a set of constants for numerous media types. `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML`

Answer (score 1):

Try "application/xml" see also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type#Type_application